# How to specify this.state constructor with a name

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to make multi `this.state` in `constructor` with specific name for example

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
      const loginData = this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
        };
       const options = this.state = {
            redirect: false,
            showAlert: false,
        };
}
```

I'm just wondering if there's a way to do that.

Comment: why do you possibly want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the structure like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        loginData: {
            username: '',
            password: '',
        },
        options: {
            redirect: false,
            showAlert: false,
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: this.state.loginData.username - for username, and the same way for other keys

Comment: this.state.loginData.username - get the value of username field
this.setState - it's a function, for saving data to the state:
for example, if you want to save login name = user you should write - this.setState({ loginData: {...this.state.loginData, username: 'user'}})

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Looking at your question I guess you could want something like this:

```
this.state = {
  loginData: { username: '', password: '' },
  options: { redirect: false, showAlert: false }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1) I dont think that is possible.

2) This should work:

this.state = {

loginData: {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  },

options: {
    redirect: false,
    showAlert: false
  }
}

And calling this.state.loginData would have the same effect